# Duration of torrent activity and ISP tracking

Tags: vpn, p2p

The only reason I use BitTorrent is to download Linux distros, Open source apps and large documentation files. My ISP contacted me once and warned me:

> Ok, you aren't downloading anything illegal or pirated, but our network traffic doesn't allow p2p in general (implying that I should stop).

So, I chose a VPN and tunneled p2p client through it and soon committed a mistake of not deleting my default gateway from the routing table. When the ISP connection dropped, and reconnected later, VPN  was still attempting a reconnection. Meanwhile the torrent client might've switched to the default gateway and resumed downloading **(for half an hour)** exposing my IP to the tracker pool.

My doubt is, would the above-mentioned scenario expose my torrent-IP permanently to the ISP? Are the peer-IP's kept forever in the tracker's list? How long does it take for an agency (like the ISP) to gather such data.

Comment: This is difficult to answer, as no one outside of the (unspecified) ISP could really tell you. I wouldn't expect a helpful response to the current question.

Comment: @KnightOfNi I agree. But it would help to know whether one's IP is still retained among the trackers even after the torrent is deleted.